# How to display list using SPARQL

Tags: sql, subquery, sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to show the list of Charities from this page - http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Charitable_organizations

The list is in `is dct:subject of` property, I have made a query but it doesn't work.

**QUERY**

```
WHERE {
         ?s dbo:type dbr:Charitable_organization .
      }
```

I do kind of know how to use SPARQL with DBPEDIA but am unsure how to use the `dct:subject` part and display the `dbr:'

Using the site- http://dbpedia.org/sparql to execute queries. So any help on how I can show the list of charities from that website? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>        
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
## Added ##
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT * 
WHERE {
         ?s dbo:type dbr:Charitable_organization .
      }
```

**Links**

- Live Results Page [Link](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0APREFIX%20type%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20prop%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fs%20dbo%3Atype%20dbr%3ACharitable_organization%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on).
- Live Query Definition [Link](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0APREFIX%20type%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20prop%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20*%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fs%20dbo%3Atype%20dbr%3ACharitable_organization%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on).

Comment: Thanks it worked! may I ask what does the dbo:type part do?

Comment: This is the property resp. predicate of the triple. And it describes or better said denotes the relationship between subject and object. Or what do you mean?